# JMX Not visible in jvm option in application registered in spring boot admin dashboard

Tags: spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-admin

After migrating spring-boot-admin-starter-client version to 2.7.8, the jmx option is not visible in jvm option of my application registered on spring boot admin dashboard.I added the below dependency.

implementation group: 'de.codecentric', name: 'spring-boot-admin-starter-client', version: '2.7.8'.

The jmx is visible with the below dependency

implementation group: 'de.codecentric', name: 'spring-boot-admin-starter-client', version: '2.1.2'

i upgraded the spring-boot-admin-starter-client version to 2.7.8 . then the problem starts